# What algorithm sorts new and duplicate values in linear time using no extra space?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

[7,1,2,3,2,4,1,5,6]

What algorithm sorts new and duplicate values in linear time using no extra space?

Counting sort sorts the unique values as far as I know, and other comparision sorts are not O(n).

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. In what sense does [counting sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) not sort duplicate values? (Maybe post the expected result for your example?)

Comment: I read that counting sort sorts using values as indexes. That's why I guessed. @ruakh If you think this is wrong, then I will read the counting sort again.

Comment: Counting Sort is good for this because it has `O(n+k)` time for best, average and worst cases. I would also suggest using a hash table to count frequencies of the numbers, then sort the hashtable, then replace the array with these sorted values.

Comment: @RoadRunner Please put that as a somewhat detailed answer. I will select it.

Comment: @RoadRunner the OP mentioned "using no extra space". AFAIK Counting sort does use extra space for building the hash table.

Comment: What counting sort counts is duplicate values. But as babon says, it requires extra storage to hold the counts.

Comment: @babon I don't see how your going to not use extra space when using counting sort. Using a hash table would be the optimal way of storing the counts, so extra spaced is forced here. If OP doesnt want extra space, counting sort is out of the question.

Comment: @roadrunner: a hash table might be reasonable if the list you are sorting is much smaller than the range of the elements (sort 100 32-bit integers). However, to finish the sort you need to traverse the hash table in order by key, which you cannot do in O(n) if the range of values is much larger than n. Normally, one would use counting sort only when the range of values is O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really well-posed, because the problem with counting sort is not that it doesn't sort duplicate values (it sorts them just fine, which is why it's "counting sort" and not "flag-setting sort"), but rather (as [babon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4845636/babon) points out above) that counting sort requires at least O(*k*) extra space, where *k* is the number of distinct values in the array.

But setting that aside . . . if these are finite-sized integers (such as 32-bit integers) you can use an [American flag sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_flag_sort), which is an in-place variant of radix sort. Assuming you want the bare minimum amount of extra space (you say "no extra space", but that's impossible, because even a single index variable `i` constitutes "extra space"), you can proceed as follows:

- First, partition the elements that are less than `0` before the elements that are greater than or equal to `0`. (You can do this the same way as you would [segregate even and odd numbers](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segregate-even-and-odd-numbers/), except that you use `& 0x8000` instead of `% 2`.)
- Next, within the first (less-than-`0`) partition, partition the elements that are less than `0xC000` before the elements that are greater than or equal to it; and in the second (greater-than-or-equal-to-`0`) partition, partition the elements that are less than `0x4000` before the elements that are greater than or equal to `0x4000`. (You can use the same approach for this as for the previous step, except that you also need to keep watch for when you transition from one partition to the other.)
- And, similarly for each subsequent bit.

Overall, this involves 32 passes through the array (if these are 32-bit integers), so it's O(32*n*) = O(*n*).